# Data massaging in json response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object

I have written the following code for in angular for a $http get service call

```
  var country = "http://localhost:3000/json/country.json";
        $http.get(timeZoneUrl).then(function (response) {
            $ctrl.timezone = response.data;
            console.log(response.data);
        });
```

Everything works fine and i am getting response as below.

```
  [{
    "region": "Africa",
    "country": "South Africa"
  },
  {
    "region": "Europe",
    "country": "Spain"
  }];
```

I would like to have the json response massaged and to update the key from the UI. i want the response to be in the following format

```
 [{
     "value": "Africa",
     "label": "South Africa"
   },
   {
     "value": "Europe",
     "label": "Spain"
 }];
```

Comment: What kind of massage do you want to give to your JSON response?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map);

```js
var countries = [{"region": "Africa","country": "South Africa"},{"region": "Europe","country": "Spain"}],
    formattedCountries = countries.map(function(c) {
      return {
        'value': c.region,
        'label': c.country
      };
    });

console.log(formattedCountries);
```